# Counting rows in one table to check if they match value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Two tables:

attendee_tables:
company_id int,
ind_company_name varchar,
tickets int

attendees:
company_id int,
first_name varchar,
last_name varchar,

`attendee_tables` contains a column called tickets that holds the number of tickets a company purchased. The `attendees` table are the registrants. I would like a query that returns the companies and count of who are not in the `attendees` table OR they have do not have the same number of entries in `attendees` as the number of tickets they have in `attendees_tables`.

What I have so far :

```
select    
    t.company_id,  
    t.ind_company_name,  
    sum(t.tickets)  
from  
    attendee_tables t 
left outer join 
    attendees a  
        on t.company_id = a.company_id  
where  
    a.company_id is null  
group by  
    t.company_id, t.ind_company_name  
order by  
    sum(t.tickets)
```

This seems to be working correctly giving me the first part of my question, the companies who do not have any entries in the `attendees` table.

Comment: If a company has all attendees accounted for, do you need a row for them showing zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.company_id, t.ind_company_name, t.tickets attendee_tables_Tickets, a.Tickets attendees_Tickets
FROM attendee_tables t 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) Tickets FROM attendees GROUP BY company_id) a  
    ON t.company_id = a.company_id  
WHERE t.tickets <> ISNULL(a.Tickets,0) OR A.company_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the where to filter out only those rows that mismatch

```
select  
   t.company_id, 
   t.ind_company_name, 
   t.tickets, 
   isnull(attcnt.attendeecount, 0) as attendeecount
from  attendee_tables t 
left join 
  (select company_id, count(*) as attendeecount from attendees group by company_id) attcnt
on attcnt.company_id = t.company_id
-- where t.tickets <> attcnt.attendeecount
```